# Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be such that $\underline{0}$ is a local minimum point for every algebraic curve, is it $0$ a local minimum point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, maxima-minima, algebraic-curves

Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a real function such that $\underline{0}$ is a local minimum point for $f$ on every algebraic curve, i.e. for every [algebraic curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve) $C$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that if $x \in B_{\epsilon}(\underline{0}) \cap C$ then $f(0) \leq f(x)$

Where  $B_{\epsilon}(0) := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \; : \; ||x|| < \epsilon \}$ and $C$ is the set of points that belongs to the algebraic curve

(Observe that $\epsilon$ depends on $C$).

Is it true that $\underline{0}$ is necessarily local minimum point for $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably we can give an explicit example, but being lazy we can use [Whitney extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) to only have to talk about some of the values at some points or sets of points, and the rest gets filled up by Whitney.

Consider the sequence of points $p_n=(1/n, e^{-n!})$ and circles $c_n=\{\|x-p_n\|=e^{-n!}\}$. The $e^{-n!}$ is there to decrease faster than any power. By [Lojasiewicz's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81ojasiewicz_inequality), an algebraic curve is not going to intersect infinitely many of the $p_n$ or of the $c_n$.

Let's define a function $f$ such that $f(p_n)=-1/n$, the Taylor series of $f$ is zero at every point of $c_n$, and $f(0)=0$. Whitney gives us some smooth function on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that takes these values. In the exterior of the union of all $c_n$ and the origin, we can replace $f$ by $f^2$, just to make it non-negative there.

You can see now that on an algebraic curve passing through the origin, there will be a neighborhood of the origin not intersecting the $c_n$. Therefore, $f\geq0$ on that neighborhood. So, $f(0)$ is a local minimum. However, in every neighborhood of the origin we will have points $p_n$ at which $f$ is taking negative values.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started: Let $g$ be smooth and nonnegative with $g^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k=0,1,2,\dots$. For example, take
$$g(t) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/t^2}, & t\ne 0 \\ 0, & t=0\end{cases}.$$

Write points in $\Bbb R^n$ as $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^{n-1}\times\Bbb R$, and set $$f(x,y) = \big(y-g(\|x\|)\big)(\big((y-2g(\|x\|)\big).$$
Then $f$ is negative on $R=\{g(\|x\|)<y<2g(\|x\|)\}$ but nonnegative elsewhere. Any algebraic curve passing through the origin will be in contained in the complement of $R$ and you can check that $f$ has a local minimum at $0$ when restricted to such a curve. But $f$ itself has a saddle point at $0$, since $f<0$ on $R$.